# Group by with a select column I cannot enter in the group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I wrote a query is SQL Server which selects the first_name from the customers table and then grade from the students table. It works fine without the CASE expression also works fine withing MySQL, however in SQL Server I seem to keep running into the following problem:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 81
>   Column 'papers.grade' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I do not really know why this is a problem and the only solution I found is including it in the group by as "GROUP BY first_name, grade". this however modifies my output and therefore is not usable. Could anyone please explain me why this error keeps happening? It'll be much appreciated.

My sql query

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    AVG(ISNULL(grade, 0)) AS average, 
    CASE    
        WHEN grade < 75 THEN'failing' 
        ELSE'passing' ENDAS result 
    FROM students 
    LEFT JOIN papers 
        ON papers.student_Id = students.id
        GROUP BY first_name
        ORDER BY average DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails because you have an unaggregated column in the `case` expression (`grade`) that does not belong to the `group by` clause. In most databases, this is a fatal error - although MySQL is lax about that, which can lead to suprising behaviors.

Most likely, you want:

```
SELECT 
    s.first_name, 
    AVG(ISNULL(p.grade, 0)) AS average, 
    CASE WHEN AVG(ISNULL(p.grade, 0)) < 75 THEN 'failing' ELSE 'passing' END result 
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN papers p ON p.student_Id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name
ORDER BY average DESC
```

This sets the `result` according to the average `grade` of each `student`.

Note that I added table aliases to your query, and prefixed each column with the table it belongs to; this makes the query easier to read and write, and unambiguous about the underlying tables structure.

Side note: I am quite suspicious about the `ISNULL()` construct in aggregate function `AVG()`; `AVG()` ignore `NULL`s values, so your expression causes students without grades to get the `0` average instead of `NULL`- which may not be what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, I found that using AVG(grade) within the CASE branch it works because it is aggregated date. Does this mean that there is no way of ever using non aggregated data in a group by clause? I wonder why this is, in case you might want to show some more context in the result.

The code you provided works, but it needs to drop the IFNULL as a WHEN condition expects a condition instead of a boolean. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RodneyWormsbecher: welcome. Yes, the basic rule is that *every non-aggregated column must appear in the `group by` clause*. As for `ISNULL()`, you sure can use it the `case` statement (there was a missing closing parenthese in my query, that I just added).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group by your entire CASE statement.

```
SELECT 
first_name, 
AVG(ISNULL(grade, 0)) AS average, 
CASE    
    WHEN grade < 75 THEN
        'failing' 
    ELSE
        'passing' 
END AS result 
FROM students 
LEFT JOIN papers 
    ON papers.student_Id = students.id
GROUP BY 
    first_name,
    CASE    
        WHEN grade < 75 THEN
            'failing' 
        ELSE
            'passing' 
    END
ORDER BY average DESC
```

That should get rid of the error. However, that still may not be what you are looking for.